# Date and time panel is greyed out, how do I restore it?

Tags: 13.10, indicator, date

Date and time is showing in the login screen (unity-greeter) but not when I login to my session.

When I go to date and time settings the panel is all grey :

[image: screenshot]

Any idea how to recover from this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug.

Try to reinstall `gnome-control-center` using the following commands from [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Comment: This did not work for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I had to reinstall `libmessaging-menu0` under Ubuntu 18.04 using the following commands:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libmessaging-menu0
```

I found out the above shared library was missing by running the `indicator-datetime-service` manually as

```bsh
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
```