# Calender/Time not showing up in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, calendar, date

I recently noticed that the date/time disappared from my desktop.
Until now I could see them both in the top-right corner of my system and clicking on it would show up the calender, but now it disappeared altogether
[image]

Comment: Possibly a duplication of http://askubuntu.com/questions/368062/date-and-time-panel-is-greyed-out-how-do-i-restore-it. Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: No, Will try and get back to you